# Add a new locale to OS X (/usr/share/locale)

Tags: macos, unix, python, locale

I am trying to add a new locale support to my OS X system, which I could then use in Python scripts.

It is Indonesian locale (`id_ID`) and I currently do not have it in my `/usr/share/locales` directory, `locale -a` also do not show it.

I tried adding it through OS X preferences but that does not seem to work in the same way.

What is the correct way for getting/downloading this new locale to my system? Should I compile it myself? What should I compile it from?